# Binomial-Like Distribution with Changing Probability

Tags: probability

### The Question

Assume we have $n$ multiple choice questions, the $k$-th question having $k+1$ answer choices. What is the probability that, guessing randomly, we get at least $r$ questions right?

If no general case is available, I am OK with the special case $r = \left\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\right\rfloor + 1$.

#### Example

Assume we have four different multiple choice questions.

> 1. Question 1
>
>    - Choice A
>    - Choice B
> 2. Question 2
>
>    - Choice A
>    - Choice B
>    - Choice C
> 3. Question 3
>
>    - Choice A
>    - Choice B
>    - Choice C
>    - Choice D
> 4. Question 4
>
>    - Choice A
>    - Choice B
>    - Choice C
>    - Choice D
>    - Choice E

If we choose the answer to each question at random, what is the probability we get at least three right? (By constructing a probability tree, I get the answer as $11/120$.)

Comment: I can't seem to modify it to work, but something along the lines of $\frac{C(n,r)}{(n+1)!}$ might get you started

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $U_k$ be an indicator random variable, equal to 1 if the $k$-th question has been guessed correctly. Clearly $(U_1, U_2,\ldots,U_n)$ are independent Bernoulli random variables with $\mathbb{E}\left(U_k\right) = \frac{1}{k+1}$.

The total number of correct guesses equals:
$$
    X = \sum_{k=1}^n U_k
$$
The moment generating function of $X$ is easy to find:
$$
  \mathcal{P}_X\left(z\right) = \mathbb{E}\left(z^X\right) = \prod_{k=1}^n \mathbb{E}\left(z^{U_k}\right) = \prod_{k=1}^n \frac{k+z}{k+1} = \frac{1}{z} \frac{(z)_{n+1}}{(n+1)!} = \frac{1}{(n+1)!} \sum_{k=0}^n z^k s(n+1,k+1)
$$
where $s(n,m)$ denote [unsigned Stirling numbers of the first kind](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_first_kind#Unsigned_Stirling_numbers_of_the_first_kind). Thus:$$
   \mathbb{P}\left(X=m\right) = \frac{s(n+1,m+1)}{(n+1)!} [ 1 \leqslant m \leqslant n ]
$$
The probability of getting at least $r$ equals:
$$
   \mathbb{P}\left(X \geqslant r\right) = \sum_{m=r}^{n} \frac{s(n+1,m+1)}{(n+1)!}
$$

This reproduces your result for $n=4$ and $r=3$.

```
In[229]:= With[{n = 4, r = 3}, 
 Sum[Abs[StirlingS1[n + 1, m + 1]]/(n + 1)!, {m, r, n}]]

Out[229]= 11/120
```

Here is the table for $1 \leqslant n \leqslant 11$:

[image]

Comment: I've tried this for other cases and it definitely works. Thanks!

Comment: @GeorgeV.Williams You are welcome. And thank you for the interesting question.